# launched GUI beanshell but application froze

Tags: java, jar, beanshell

I ran the jar file successfully from the command prompt, and i see the beanshell 2.0 with a jellybean face small window being loaded. and then it seemed to have froze while loading.

Am i missing something, and this is from the latest beta stable jar file from [here](http://www.beanshell.org/download.html)

[image: loading image that froze]

Answer (score 0):

after running `C:\>java -jar C:\Java\jdk1.6.0_26-32\jre\lib\ext\bsh-2.0b4.jar` for about 20 times, the splash page stopped freezing, and the GUI console is launched. Opening a new command prompt and running the command doesn't seem to guarantee the GUI console will run again.

Otherwise, I found that running `java -Xrs -Xverify:none -cp bsh-2.0b4.jar bsh.Interpreter` in the command prompt is far more effective and works all the time.

Comment: I answered this question earlier. Or maybe it was later. You seem to have have asked it multiple times in different ways. In any case an executable .jar file contains a manifest file which tells the java command which class contains the `public static void main[String args]` method. By doing this, you simple need to execute the command `java -jar myfile.jar`.  However there is a quirk with Beanshell in that you also need to set the classpath to the bsh jar file before it works. In other words your command is doing what the jar is already set up to do.

Answer (score 0):

I had this on windows 10 after launching Beanstalk from Chrome. I couldn't find the process to terminate, but I just ran the bsh-2.0b4.jar file again and it works!